# php, arrays, extracting values

Tags: php, arrays

```
require_once 'include/load_it.php';
$nice = ($_GET['nice']);

$Key = 'tfvs7'; // Your API key
$remix  = new Load_Service_Con($Key);

$result = $new->product($nice)->show(array('salePrice','url'))->query();

echo $result;
```

I am trying to figure out how I can extract the values of the array and echo the values into seperate div's

Thanks

Comment: i think that you should add some code formatting :)

Comment: add `print_r ($result);` to the end, then you can find a way to use those variables.

Comment: The brackets around the `$_GET` retrieval are unecessary as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should probably read up on [PHP: Arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Assuming its a simple array (you could clarify this by posting a `var_dump($result)`.

```
foreach($result as $data) {
    echo '<div>';
    echo $data;
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment: Even if it *isn't* an array, if it is some sort of iterator / object-y thing you could always foreach it as is or do: `$result = (array) $new->product($nice)->show(array('salePrice','url'))->query();`